# Snapshot param in Collection - null given error

Tags: magento2

I am trying to list some records using the listing UI-Component and i have a Collection like:

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track\Collection 
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot $entitySnapshot,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,        
         $mainTable,
        $eventPrefix,
        $eventObject,
        $resourceModel,
        $model = 'Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Document',
        $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null       
    ) {
        $this->entitySnapshot = $entitySnapshot;
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
        $this->_eventPrefix = $eventPrefix;
        $this->_eventObject = $eventObject;
        $this->_init($model, $resourceModel);
        $this->setMainTable($mainTable);
    }
```

The above class is instatiated in my di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="shiptracker_tracking_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Tracking\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>    
<type name="Vendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Tracking\Grid\Collection">
            <arguments>         
                <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_shipment_track</argument>
                <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">sales_shipment_track_collection</argument>
                <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">sales_shipment_track_collection</argument>
                <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track</argument>
            </arguments>
        </type>
```

My problem is that when i am trying to access the listing page, i am getting the following error:

> *Recoverable Error: Argument 5 passed to Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Collection::__construct()
>   must be an instance of
>   Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\VersionControl\Snapshot, null
>   given, called in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Vendor/MyModule/Model/ResourceModel/Tracking/Grid/Collection.php
>   on line 56 and defined in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/VersionControl/Collection.php
>   on line 32*

The same constructor seems to be used by other collections without any issue.

Comment: remove var/cache and var/generation folder and try again

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused in the calling of the parent constructor:

```
  parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $connection,
            $resource
        );
```

Was missing the $entitySnapshot param. The correct is:

```
   parent::__construct(
        $entityFactory,
        $logger,
        $fetchStrategy,
        $eventManager,
        $entitySnapshot,
        $connection,
        $resource
    );
```